# Fragment no se cierra (esconde) en una activity

Tags: java, android, android-fragment

Tenía un problem con un Activity que tengo que tiene 4 fragmentos que tenía un container justo debejo del título de cada apartado. Los fragmentos al cliquear el ImageView tenían que abrirse y luego al volver a cliquear el botón se cerraban. El problema es que no se cerraban. Lo he hecho funcionar de otra forma, pero me gustaría saber porque no funcionaba mi código que había escrito antes?

Alguien me puede señalar el error?

```
mPrivacy.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.container_privacy, new PrivacyFragment(), null).addToBackStack(null).commit();

        Fragment fragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.container_privacy);
        if (fragment != null)
            if (fragment.isVisible()) {
                fragmentTransaction.hide(fragment).commit();
            } else {
                fragmentTransaction.show(fragment).commit();
            }
    });

    mSecurity.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        //Create Security Fragment
    });

    mHelp.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        //Create Help Fragment
    });

    mAbout.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        //Create About Fragment
    });

    getUserInfo();
}
```

Lo he hecho funcionar así pero quiero saber porque no funcionaba la forma de arriba

```
mPrivacy.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.container_privacy, new PrivacyFragment(), null).addToBackStack(null).commit();

        if (mFrameLayout.getVisibility() == View.GONE) {
            mFrameLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            mFrameLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Tu pregunta es saber la razòn por la cual no se esconde o muestra un `Fragment` usando:

```
fragmentTransaction.hide(fragment).commit();

fragmentTransaction.show(fragment).commit();
```

pero usando esta forma si lo realiza.

```
 mFrameLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);

 mFrameLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

la razòn la puedes encontrar en las definiciones de los mètodos de [FragmentTransaction](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/FragmentTransaction):

> [hide()](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/FragmentTransaction#hide(androidx.fragment.app.Fragment)) Esconde un fragmento existente. Esto solo es relevante
>   para los fragmentos cuyas vistas se han agregado a un contenedor, ya
>   que esto hará que la vista esté oculta.
>
> [show()](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/FragmentTransaction#show(androidx.fragment.app.Fragment)) Muestra un fragmento previamente oculto. Esto solo es
>   relevante para los fragmentos cuyas vistas se han agregado a un
>   contenedor, ya que esto hará que se muestre la vista.

**Estos mètodos solo funcionan si agregaste mediante una transacciòn el Fragment, de otra forma no funcionarian.**

Comment: Pero es justo lo que había hecho o no? El fragmento lo tengo en un contenedor que tiene que abrirse al pulsar el ImageView. Y luego esconderse al volver a pulsarlo? ```container_privacy``` es el contenedor que tengo en  el layout para poder meter allí el fragmento... O algo se me escapa? Se abre ```show``` pero luego no se esconde ```hide```

Answer (score 0):

He revisado tu codigo y he detectado el problema, en tu codigo original, para esconder y hacer show nuevamente al fragment, estas utilizando el mismo objeto FragmentTransaction que estas utilizando para agregar el fragmento al contenedor, y debes recordar que en los FragmentTransaction, todos los add hide y shows que coloques se realizaran, cada vez que hagas commit a la transaction, para arreglar el codigo original debes hacer nuevos objetos FragmentTransaction para invocar hide() y show() de la siguiente manera:

```
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.container_privacy, new PrivacyFragment(), null).addToBackStack(null).commit();

Fragment fragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.container_privacy);
if (fragment != null)
    if (fragment.isVisible()) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().hide(fragment).commit();
    } else {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().show(fragment).commit();
    }
```

});

En el codigo podras observar que obtengo nuevas Fragment Transaction para ocultar y mostrar el fragmento.

Comment: Voy a ver si funciona. Gracias por explicármelo. Ahora aceptaré la respuesta si me funciona

Comment: Tío, he cambiado el código para reflejar lo que tienes aquí, pero no ha funcionado... No se abre ni se cierra el fragmento.